# Performing mathematical operations on value in lists

Tags: python, list, math, floating-point

I am trying to add a value in a list to an outside integer.

The list is from a `.text` file **"apiresp"**:

```
APIlines = []      # Declare an empty list named APIlines.

with open ('apiresp.txt', 'rt') as myfile: # Open airesp.txt for reading text data.
     
    
    for APIline in myfile:         # For each line, stored as myfile,       
        
        APIlines.append(APIline)       # add its contents to APIlines.          
    
        hpa = (APIlines[5]) 

# function to extract numbers from string
s = [float(s) for s in re.findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d*', hpa)] 

res = [float(ele) for ele in s]

b = []

for item in s:
    b.append(float(item)) # convert the string to a float which we can use in mathematical operations

res1 = res + 1

print(res1)
```

I was under the impression that line 10 would 'extract' the object from the list into a float and thus we can use for mathematical operations, but I'm very new to this so I'm sorry if it's a
stupid question/assumption.

It's returning the following error:

```
line 36, in <module>
      res1 = res + 1 
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
```

This is for a late school project so any help would be appreciated. Thanks guys :)

Comment: Could you please format your code with triple backticks?

Answer (score 1):

change your line :

```
res1 = res + 1
```

to :

```
res1 =[x+1 for x in res]
```

with lists the (+) operator used for concatenating lists:

```
l=[1,2,3]
x=[4,5,6]
print(l+x)
>>>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

and (*) used for repeating list as in:

```
print(l*3)
>>>[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

to increment list values you need to process list items one by one inside a loop or using comprehension expressions.

Comment: Thanks man that's working :) How do you format the code in that way? It's my first post and I tried to with "\\\" but it doesn't seem to have worked. Got a feeling that's why I've got negative votes lol

Comment: paste your code then select it and click the {}  button on the toolbar. yes it is very important to post code well formatted and clean otherwise it will be hard to understand what you are trying to do with it . anyway welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

use a list comprehension: res1 = [item+1 for item in res]
the + operator for lists concatenates, aka it joins lists together.